# How to structure table in MySQL for group chat application?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-8.0

I'm making a messaging application, and I need a way to organize and store messages. I was thinking something like a table that had all the group chat IDs and who was in which group chat, but MySQL doesn't have a list functionality. For the actual messages, I was thinking one large table with the group chat IDs and the message ID. To be honest, I really don't have a good way to approach this. I was even considering making a table for every group chat. How should I structure a database for a group messaging application?

Comment: A million rows, even a billion rows, is not too much for any relational database to handle.

Answer (score 3):

With relational databases, or mostly-relational databases as is the case with MySQL, you should think mostly in terms of entities and relationships.

You might want one table for each of the following entities:

- **messages**: the actual messages and a reference to the user (author)
- **users**: details such as user name, email address, ...
- **groups**: maybe just the name of the group
- **group memberships**: one row per user per group. This allows for a many-to-many relationship, so that many users can be in many groups at the same time.

So then you could have tables maybe like such:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id bigint unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  -- other user columns here
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
  group_id bigint unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  groupname varchar(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  -- other group columns here
);

CREATE TABLE group_users (
  group_id bigint unsigned,
  user_id bigint unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id, user_id),
  CONSTRAINT group_users_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (group_id),
  CONSTRAINT group_users_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
  message_id bigint unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id bigint unsigned,
  message TEXT,
  -- other columns here, e.g. timestamp
  CONSTRAINT messages_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)    
);
```

**Edit**

The lines starting with [`CONSTRAINT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) specify foreign keys which enforce integrity of data between the tables. E.g. they will prevent rows from being deleted in the `users` table that are referenced in the `messages` table.

To retrieve a list of users in a particular group, use a query like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN group_users gu USING (user_id)
WHERE gu.group_id = 3;
```

The [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) means the query will only retrieve the `users` who have at least one row in the `group_users` table, and the `WHERE` ensures that we only retrieve results for group_id 3.

Comment: Could you further explain the lines starting with `CONSTRAINT`, and also explain how/where this code stores a list of users in a group?

Comment: Hi @AlexJone - I've edited the answer to be (hopefully) a bit more clear on these issues.